# How do I deploy specific tag of my docker image in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

My deployment JSON file have following entry from my image, where 49 is build number. I'm confused how do I use VSTS or kubectl to replace that number with each incremental build. VSTS provides command line options to cubectl command, is it possible to specify something like `cubectl -f file.json -imagetag $TAG` or something?

```
"containers": [
          {
            "name": "jietest",
            "image": "myreg.azurecr.io/jietest:49",
            "resources": {},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`kubectl set image`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/v1.8/#-em-image-em-) to update container image of a resource.

For example: `kubectl set image -f file.json jietest=myreg.azurecr.io/jietest:$TAG`.